# Transpose JSON array index column values into rows & export to CSV

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, indexing, export-to-csv

I have a JSON file with below format:

```json
[
        {
            "id":  "12345",
            "name": "test_group",
            "members":  
                [
                    {
                        "id":  "11111",
                        "name": "test_member_1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":  "22222",
                        "name": "test_member_2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":  "33333",
                        "name": "test_member_3"
                    }
                ]
        }
]
```

My requirement is to convert these into below format/output to CSV:

```
groupId,groupName,memberId,memberName
12345,test_group,11111,test_member_1
12345,test_group,22222,test_member_2
12345,test_group,33333,test_member_3
```

I am able to get the array index values as concatenated strings in one column using below code, but need the output in above format only:

```
$jsonfile = 'C:\newjsonfile.json'
$outputcsv = 'C:\newcsvfile.csv'
$fields=@(
     @{Name='groupId';Expression={$_.id}}
    ,@{Name='groupName';Expression={$_.name}}
    ,@{Name='memberId';Expression={$_.members.id, -join '|~|'}}
    ,@{Name='memberName';Expression={$_.members.name -join '|~|'}}
)
(Get-Content $jsonfile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) |
    Select-Object -Property $fields |
    Export-Csv $outputcsv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

CSV Output from above query:

```
groupId, groupName,  memberId,              memberName                                   
----- ---------  --------              ----------                                   
12345, test_group, {11111 |~| 22222 |~| 33333}, {test_member_1 |~| test_member_2 |~| test_member_3}
```

Please help/suggest in resolving this query in PowerShell.
Current version is:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  407
```

Comment: Excellent !! That worked perfectly. Thank you Ansgar Wiechers. You Rock !! Just one small observation though... when the opening curly brace of ForEach-Object goes to the next line (was trying to do some indentation of the code), the shell asks to provide the process id, could you please explain why such behavior ?                              
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

Comment: Like other interpreters PowerShell parses code line by line. In some situations the parser recognizes an incomplete statement and automatically continues at the next line (like trailing commas or pipes, or operators without a second operand). If it doesn't it will either throw a syntax error or prompt for missing arguments, which is what's happening in your case. It's not asking for a process ID, though, but for a scriptblock to pass to the parameter `-Process` (which also is the first positional parameter, so `ForEach-Object {...}` and `ForEach-Object -Process {...}` are the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to combine information from a parent object with information from nested child objects. To do that you need to store the information from the parent in variables and then inject it when processing the child objects:

```
(Get-Content $jsonfile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object {
    $gid  = $_.id
    $name = $_.name
    $_.members |
        Select-Object @{n='groupId';e={$gid}},
            @{n='groupName';e={$name}},
            @{n='memberId';e={$_.id}},
            @{n='memberName';e={$_.name}}
} | Export-Csv $outputcsv -NoType -Force
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ansgar. Really appreciate it !! One more observation during my actual code run with an actual large json file with such structure, I am seeing that shell is returning below key:values after every set of data and exporting this as blank rows in the CSV file:                                                         
 Key   : e
Value : $gid
Name  : e

Key   : n
Value : userID
Name  : n

Key   : e
Value : $_.id
Name  : e How can I get rid of these ?

Comment: @ManiK I have no idea what you're talking about. Please update your question with a more detailed description.

Comment: Hey, please never mind, there were some mistakes in my own code but got it fixed now. Thanks a lot anyways.